# Position of content above the main navigation

Tags: navigation

Had a meeting with our Product Manager yesterday and he's requested that we put content above our site design's main navigation.

Specifically, his request was to put the end-clients logo in the top right-hand corner and the last sync date of their file in the top left.

[image]

I tend disagree with this layout, but I can put my finger on why.

Is there any established convention for where the logo is positioned in the user interface AND/OR where the software status information should be positioned?

This will provide some ideas on how I can persuade our Product Manager to reconsider this design idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using some relevant content above the main navigation bar is not a relevant problem. Lot of sites has this kind of structure.

Take a look for example to Ebay where you can see this kind of layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly common request, especially if your product can be white labeled. If clients use this externally as a service then they'll want others to perceive it as their offering. I'd question the use of both your company's logo AND the client's logo in this case.

Comment: Without knowing the context, I'd say it's a bit odd for the "last sync" information to have such prominence. Unless, of course, it is really important for users to know!

Answer (score 0):

I also don't see a problem in such request. The amount of information (and, thus, the space it occupies) is small, so it doesn't detract users' **attention**. Moreover, this information doesn't represent **real content** - it's just some **branding** information. I'd advise you to **reconsider your view** on this non-significant issue.

Comment: Having read these comments, I see that I was wrong in my thinking. Thanks for your input.